# Como implementar una clase que herede de QGraphicsItem y se comporte como un QGraphicsItemGroup

Tags: c++, qt

estoy trabajando en un proyecto donde he necesitado heredar de la clase `QGraphicsItem` de Qt ya que necesitaba tener unos `QGraphicsItem` con unas características especiales (modificación de tamaño de líneas, en función al zoom, ajuste del boundingRect a la forma del objeto a mostrar, ...).

El caso es que me he topado ahora con la necesidad de tener una clase propia que se comporte como un `QGraphicsItemGroup` pero he encontrado problemas a la hora de implementar las clases **paint** y **boundingRect** de la misma.

A continuación para que se entienda mejor mi caso os muestro un diagrama de clases de como tengo actualmente mi código:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como ya he dicho, el principal problema es que al heredar de un `QGraphicsItem` tengo que implementar sus métodos **paint** y **boundingRect**. He seguido el mismo patrón que usa el `QGraphicsItemGroup`, implementando el método **addToGroup** pero no he conseguido que se muestre nada.

La otra opción que he probado es que `MyGraphicsItemGroup` herede también de `QGraphicsItemGroup`, pero con esto no consigo eliminar la necesidad de implemetar los métodos anteriormente citados.

Este es el código de MyGraphicsItemGroup:

```
QGraphicsItemGroup *group;

MyGraphicsItemGroup::MyGraphicsItemGroup()
{
    group = new QGraphicsItemGroup();
}

QRectF MyGraphicsItemGroup::boundingRect() const
{
    return group->boundingRect();
}

void MyGraphicsItemGroup::paint(QPainter * painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem * option, QWidget * widget)
{
    group->paint(painter, option, widget);
}
```

Estaría muy agradecido si alguien pudiera darme alguna idea de como solventar este problema.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Sería recomendable que incluyeses un ejemplo mínimo (pero mínimo de verdad) que reproduzca el problema. Decir que tienes problemas sin aportar código sirve más bien de poco de cara a darte soluciones

Comment: @eferion ahora te adjunto el código de mi clase GraphicsItemGroup

Comment: Edita la pregunta y publica ahí el ejemplo, por favor. Los enlaces a sitios externos deben ser complementos. Lo comento por si acaso

Comment: El código dista mucho de ser un ejemplo mínimo que reproduzca el problema. Es decir, si que es mínimo, pero con ese código es imposible que cualquiera pueda reproducir el problema y darte una solución

Comment: @eferion eso es justo lo que necesitas ver del método, es que no hay más. Cuando heredas de QGraphicsItem solo debes implementar esos dos métodos(para que funcione).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La funcionalidad de `QGraphicsItemGroup` puede simplemente emularse utilizando `QGraphicItem::setParentItem()`. Puedes tener un `QGraphicItem` vacio que funciones como un grupo o layer.

Comment: muchas gracias por tu respuesta. No conocía este comportamiento de los QGraphicsItem. Acabo de hacer una prueba y obtengo un resultado aceptable.

Comment: de nada :) , si los `QGraphicsItem` pueden agruparse en estructuras de arbol, y el elemento padre propagara las transformacion(traslacion, rotaciones y escalas) a sus hijos. Ademas de otras propiedades. Saludos!